# Farewell fellow visitors: Dan Hulme retires as moderator

Tags: discussion

I'm writing to you today to let you all know I'll be stepping down from the post of moderator, effective when the (newly announced) election happens. When I first joined this site, it was not just a hobby for me, but a professional interest, as a developer of Android apps and games, and of the OS itself. I hoped to reach out to my own users, and to help bring the deep knowledge of Android to everyone here, to solve the questions that can only be answered as a developer.

But now it's two years since I last worked on Android as a developer, and though I still use an Android phone, I'm not as active on the site as I was, and I don't have that interest to research those hard technical questions. The site's just not the same part of my daily routine that it used to be. We were due for an election anyway, so it seems like the right time for me to step back from moderation duties and encourage some new input from those who are more active on the site now.

I'll still pop in on the review queues occasionally, but I won't be casting the final vote any more. I hope you all continue to encourage asking and answering technical questions when they're of interest to non-developers, as well as the more everyday "I flashed my phone and it won't boot any more" troubleshooting.

Thanks to all those who originally elected me, and I hope you'll remember to vote in the upcoming election. Chatting with moderators on other sites really made me appreciate how friendly and drama-free our community is. We have some good people who I'm sure will become great moderators.

Comment: Thanks Dan! It was very good to have you – as a user on Android.SE as well as co-mod. Glad to read the former will remain :)

Comment: Thanks for all of your hard work!

Comment: -1 because you're great and helpful and I don't want to see you go, sorry to hear that

Comment: Off-topic: I see eldarerathis also retired but see no announcement

Comment: @Dan Thanks for your overall contributions, even before I knew this site, we had some funny moments esp in chat, but that also helped me grow on this site as I am still a relatively ameuter user but looking forward to learn more.

Comment: @iBug The official message will come out when the election is announced and the diamonds are removed. I hope eldarerathis will write a personal message too, but it's up to him. He may prefer to do it afterwards.

Comment: I'm not good at thanking people, fellas, but I'll let an upvote express my gratitude towards a man who had the patience to explain a newbie the importance of flagging. Or rather, the importance of *not flagging until you're sure*.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks a lot Dan for your work as a Moderator and as a learned and a trusted user of this site. While I find your answers truly insightful and inspiring (one of those answers which actually inspired me to start contributing to this site), I equally appreciate your work as a Moderator.

I was one of the candidates running up for elections back in 2016, and while I lost and kind of felt bad because I lost to you (a momentary emotion, usual to mortals; and Izzy was sure to win anyway, so I was competing with you mostly :D), I gradually realized that the community chose a much better person as a Moderator than what I could be back than.

You brought to the table the kind of patience as a Moderator I didn't know  in person. (I think I failed to witness that in other Mods before 2016 was mostly because earlier the Mods were understaffed and under heavy janitorial work load so exercising that much patience might have been detrimental to the site, so they did what they thought was best for the site which I appreciate equally).

You started salvaging those borderline developer-cum-end-user oriented questions which I *et al* hastily thought would be closed as off-topic. One of the distinct trait I noted was that you often let the community decide what to do with questions which introduced ambiguity when deciding the scope of the concerned questions.  Furthermore, unless somebody else responded first, you (Izzy too) always remained in site's room, welcomed the visitors as a host and guided them gently.

My personal interaction with you further strengthened my respect for you as a Moderator, especially when I brought to Mods' concern issues which were somewhat unhealthy to the community, and which sometimes I brought with emotions leading to indiscreet engagement. But, you always exercised that basic trait of a Moderator to remain cool, see the facts as it is, and never misuse or abuse the power no matter if it solves the problem in the short run.

I'm not good with memory so that's what I could recall. That been said, thank you again Dan for helping us fellow users, along with our other hard working Moderators, to focus on that which matters most to us (asking quality questions and answering insightful answers)

Comment: Fully agree and you expressed it better :) and I hope you are planning to contest now